# fetch data from tables of different databases in node js express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am running the following query. This query is not fetching data from the tables of two different databases db1 and db2. I know I can fetch data from the tables of a single database. I have tried searching for the solution. But I could not get a solution.

var mysql  = require('mysql');

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: _host,
    user: _user,
    password : _password,
    database : _database
});

 connection.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) {
   console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
   return;
   }

 });



query = `SELECT db1.users.username, db2.posts.post_id from db1.users, db2.posts where db2.posts.user_id=db1.user.id`;


connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
if (error) throw error;


  res.send(results);
});

connection.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** You can use MySQL to query multiple different databases with a single query, *as long as all the databases are resident on the same server.* (If they are on different servers, there are ways to do what you want, but you'll require the assistance of a skilled database administrator.)

The connections you create are not to the database, they are **to the server**. Once you have a connection to the server, you can query multiple databases as long as your `user` has permission to access them.

Your query has a mistake in it.  You should mention `db1.users.id` rather than `db1.id`.

And, you should use modern SQL with JOIN / ON. The comma-join syntax you used has been obsolete for almost three decades. Try this.

```
SELECT u.username, p.post_id
  FROM db1.users u
  JOIN db2.posts p ON p.user_id = u.id
```

When debugging this sort of thing you should consider using `console.error()` a bit more. Something like this for error handling?

```
      connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            console.error (query, error);
            return next(error);   // if you're in node/express
            throw (error);        // if you're not in node/express
        }
        res.send(results);
      });
```

Comment: const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: _host,
    user: _user,
    password : _password,
    database : _database
});


It is connecting to only one database. There is no connection of the second database.